# Div has right margin only on iphone

Tags: ios, css, mobile, responsive-design, margins

On iPhone the divs masterhead, middleline, middle, bottomline, bottom, colophonline and colophon doesn't reach all the way on the right side. But on the desktop they do. I wonder why. I've tried to apply negative margins to the divs but it didn't change a thing. unfortunately I have not tried it on iPad.

The site:
http://www.domda.se

Comment: Demos are great, but once you solve the problem this question becomes useless for others.  Please construct the question so that it can live on and remain useful to others.  i.e. - include the relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried using the viewport meta-tag?

Comment: First, fix your [html validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdomda.se%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Second, I see a right margin in my desktop version of Safari that's causing a horizontal scroll-bar no matter how wide I make the window.  Solve this and I'll bet your original problem goes away.

Comment: What is `padding-right: 10px;` doing on `#colophon` (inside `style.css`)?  It's causing a annoying horizontal scroll-bar until I remove it.  Try getting rid of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of serious [HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://domda.se/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Stray tags can affect your layout and chances are great that differences between browsers will be noticeable.

Secondly, I'm seeing a right side space (margin or padding?) within my desktop version of Safari.  This space is causing a perpetual horizontal scroll-bar.  No matter how wide I make the window, all the way to 1900+ pixels, the scroll-bar remains.

When I remove `padding-right: 10px;` from your `#colophon` element located in the `style.css` file, the right side spacing issue vanishes and so does the annoying scroll-bar.

When I pull up your site on iOS, I'm seeing your issue and I believe it's caused by this right side padding on `#colophon`.

I'm not sure what the purpose is, but I think you can safely delete this `padding-right: 10px;` without detriment.  Although, you need to clear your HTML validation errors and test in all browsers to be sure.